# Representations - Tensor Product prove properties of tensor product

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products

I have a problem:
Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional complex vector space and let $B=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ denote the elements of a chosen basis. Let $\rho:G \to GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation. Let $T:V \bigotimes V \to V \bigotimes V$ be the automorphism defined by $T(e_i \bigotimes e_j)=e_j \bigotimes e_i$. Show that $T(v \bigotimes w)=w \bigotimes v$ for any $v, w \in V$ and that $T^2 = Id_{V \bigotimes V}$.
I get the feeling that this is probably really easy to prove, but I'm having some notational issues. I understand that a transformation can be defined by what it does to the elements of a basis. However, I don't really know what $T(w \bigotimes v)$ looks like since it's not defined explicitly for an element $w \bigotimes v$. The outer product in the case of $w \bigotimes v$ is matrix multiplication, correct? So then is $T(v \bigotimes w)=(e_j \bigotimes e_i)(v \bigotimes w)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Often authors restrict `\bigotimes` to $n$-fold tensor products (same thing with `\oplus`), so that we would have things like $v\otimes w\in V\otimes W$ versus $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n V_i$. | Given bases $\cal B_1$ and $\cal B_2$ for vector spaces $V$ and $W$, do you know that $\{u\otimes v:u\in{\cal B}_1, v\in{\cal B}_2\}$ is a basis for $V\otimes W$? If so, then given a basis for $V$, you *do* actually happen to know what the pure tensors $v\otimes w$ in $V\otimes V$ look like, and since $T$ is linear this means you know what $T(v\otimes w)$ looks like.

Comment: You *can* endow $V\otimes V$ with a multiplication operation using an ordered basis, where we view $e_i\otimes e_j$ as the matrix with a $1$ in the $ij$-entry and $0$ everywhere else (and every element of $V\otimes V$ is a linear combination of these things, so can be viewed as matrices), but I don't believe this is relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors. Thus

$$T(v\otimes w)=T\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i\right)\otimes\left(\sum_{j=1}^n b_je_j\right)\right)$$

$$=T\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_ib_j(e_i\otimes e_j)\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_ib_jT(e_i\otimes e_j)=\cdots $$

(Try and figure out the rest; if need be, specialize to $n=2$ to follow the above by hand.)

For the latter claim, use the fact that if two linear transformations agree on basis vectors, i.e. if we know that $T_1(e_i)=T_2(e_i)$ for every basis vector $e_i$, then we know $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equal.

Comment: What's the justification for going from step 2 to step 3 there? Why can you distribute the outer product into the summand? Also, for part 2 would it be valid to do something using the transformation matrix since $T$ is linear? i.e. part 1 implies that $T(v \otimes w)= w \otimes v$ so that $T^2(v \otimes w) = T(w \otimes v)= (v \otimes w)$

Comment: @doliver The justification is in how the tensor symbol works: it is bilinear. That is, $$(a+b)\otimes(c+d)=a\otimes c+a\otimes d+b\otimes c+b\otimes d \\ (\lambda a)\otimes b=\lambda(a\otimes b)=a\otimes(\lambda b),$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are vectors and $\lambda$ any scalar. I recommend getting acquainted with how $V\otimes W$ looks: the defining features are that elements of the form $v\otimes w$ (where $v\in V,w\in W$) span the space $V\otimes W$, and that the $\otimes$ symbol is bilinear. This allows us to form a basis for $V\otimes W$ out of bases for $V,W$, as a I describe in another comment.

Comment: As for part two, noting that $T^2$ acts as the identity on the pure tensors (those that can be represented as $v\otimes w$) is indeed sufficient because pure tensors span the whole space $V\otimes W$ (dunno about "something using transformation matrix" as a description of this though). That is, if two linear transformations agree on a spanning set, they are equal as linear maps. This is a good exercise - in fact, it applies equally well and much more generally to group homomorphisms and generating sets, as well as other contexts.